# ¿Alguien sabe como hacer un filtrado por categorías en JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Realizo un proyecto de sitio web donde tengo que filtrar los valores a sus respectivas categorías, por favor si alguien sabe....
muchas garacias!
Aquí el filtro de búsqueda con un solo elemento que es el primer select box!
/**************FILTRO DE BÚSQUEDA***************** */

```
function filtradoSearch() {
const optionTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
const filterProducts = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

for (i = 0; i < optionTabs.length; i++) {
    optionTabs[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const filter = e.target.dataset.filter;
        console.log(filter);
        filterProducts.forEach((properties) => {
            if (filter == "all") {
                properties.style.opacity = "1";
                properties.style.visibility = "visible";
            } else if (properties.classList.contains(filter)) {
                properties.style.opacity = "1";
                properties.style.visibility = "visible";
                properties.style.order = "-1";
            } else {
                properties.style.opacity = "0";
                properties.style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

}
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!, también visita [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: No has mencionado cual es el problema en concreto que presentas :/

Comment: deseo saber como podría hacer un filtrado con js de las categorias de bienes de raices para que se muestren las tarjetas hechas en html y css